# "Generate signed apk" option disabled in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, apk, signed

There are a few other people that asked the same question but none of them helped me..

I downloaded the Dendroid apk source code from [github](https://github.com/qqshow/dendroid), and as the title sais, the generate signed apk option is disabled..
What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking your project structure has an Android facet? Look under

**File** > **Project Structure** > Project Settings > **Facets**

This was missing for my project and prevented it from building.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very late, but in the hopes of helping anyone out there.

**Restarting AndroidStudio** actually worked for me. "Generate Signed APK" now appears in the Build menu.